# How to touch to move with finger in Unity3D

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I want to move my gameobject with touch for mobile devices, its like that player can touch anywhere on the screen and move his/her finger and the gameobject will move with it, not moving the touch position.

here is my script so far I did

```
void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch _touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // screen has been touched, store the touch 

        if( _touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) // finger moved 
        {
            //offset = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(_touch.position.x, _touch.position.y, theplayer.transform.position.z)) - theplayer.transform.position; 

            touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(_touch.position.x, _touch.position.y, theplayer.transform.position.z));

            theplayer.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(theplayer.transform.position, touchPos, Time.deltaTime*5f);

        }
        else if(_touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
            touchPos = Vector3.zero;
            offset = Vector3.zero;
        }

    }

} // end
```

the script is almost working but the problem is when I touch on the screen the gameobject move beneath the finger so I cant see the gameobject. I dont want this I want touch anywhere on the screen and move with finger not move to finger position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself here is the solution code.

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
             _touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // screen has been touched, store the touch 

            if(_touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began){
                isDragging = true;

                offset = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(_touch.position.x, _touch.position.y)) - theplayer.transform.position;

            }
            else if(_touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
                offset = Vector2.zero;
                isDragging = false;
            }

        }

        if(isDragging){
            Vector2 _dir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(_touch.position.x, _touch.position.y));
            _dir = _dir - offset;

            theplayer.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(theplayer.transform.position, _dir, Time.deltaTime * speed);

        }


    } // end
```

Comment: this is not complete script, you have to declare some variable like speed, isDragging (bool type)